# Modifying overloaded member operator using constness

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

Here's an overview of my problem:
I have a templated class called TWMatrix. I've overloaded the () operator such that it can take in a pair of TWMatrix and extract the corresponding entries. I want the "extraction" to produce 2 distinct results for 2 distinct cases. This has worked before when taking a pair of ints, but I'm a very stuck getting it to work for this slightly different problem:

- In one case, I want the operator to copy the entries into another TWMatrix and output it.
- In another case, I want the operator to copy the addresses of these entries into an object of type TWDataPointer, output that object.

In the first case, the method does not break constness. Indeed, the entries themselves are neither modified nor vulnerable to future modifications. In the latter, the whole point is that the TWDataPointer object can be used to modify those entries of the matrix. And so the corresponding bit of code is:

```
TWDataPointer<T> operator () (const TWMatrix<int> & I1, const TWMatrix<int> & I2)
{
     return TWDataPointer<T>(*this,I1,I2);
}

TWMatrix<T> operator () (const TWMatrix<int> & I1, const TWMatrix<int> & I2) const 
{
    return SubMat(I1,I2);
}
```

SubMat is a method that creates a matrix with the corresponding entries. It works just fine, and what values it fetches isn't very relevant here. The issue is that this second operator seems to never get called. So for example if, in my main, I write:

```
TWMatrix<double> test = D5(I1,I2);
```

The compiler complains saying:

```
error: conversion from ‘TWDataPointer<double>’ to non-scalar type ‘TWMatrix<double>’ requested
```

This is very unlike:

```
T operator () (const int & i, const int & j) const 
{
    return data[j+i*nc];
}

T& operator () (const int & i, const int & j) 
{
    return data[j+i*nc];
}
```

Which works exactly as expected, and returns either a T or T& depending on the situation. From what I understand of overloading operators, it's the const that lets the compiler distinguish which to use in which situation. So why won't this work?

Thanks in advance for the help, and feel free to ask for any extra pieces of code you may need.

PS: I already have a workaround in mind for this, and though it's not immensely ugly, it's nowhere near as simple, elegant and robust as this would be if I could get it to work.

edit: Thanks for the help so far, and I'm still looking forward to hearing your answers. In particular, I'm still confused about this:

"Going back to the int example, why does a = test(0,0) use the const version of the corresponding operator even if test is not declared const? Indeed, I've checked that this is the case using cout statements in both versions of the () operators."

Comment: Could you post declaration of `D5`?

Comment: And D5 is definitely not const? have you tried commenting out the const version for now and see whether it compiles normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a specific reason that you need to have only a single `const` of the second method?  From what it appears to me in this code, and the possible use-scenarios, while your second method is technically a `const` method, it doesn't *have* to be declared as-such.  In other word it's a method that can be used by both `const` and non-`const` versions of your class instance, and you're obviously coming up with scenarios where your class instance requires the  method when it's not a `const` object.  Thus the use of labeling your method as a `const` method just because it doesn't change the state of the instance that calls the method doesn't mean that you must label your method as `const`.

In order to work with both scenarios, I would generate two versions of `operator()` that return the `TWMatrix<T>` type ... one that is declared `const`, and one that is declared as a non-`const` method so that it can be utilized by both `const` and non-`const` class instances.   The downside though is you would have to create a separate method for returning the `TWDataPointer<T>` type since you can't overload based on just the return-type.

Comment: This would be a better approach. He could probably get rid of the `TWDataPointer` class template entirely and use `TWMatrix<T>&` on the non-const operator return if he really wants to break encapsulation.

Comment: Unfotunately that couldn't work. You can't overload an operator (or function) by only changing the output type.

Comment: @AJG85 The point of TWDataPointer is that it allows me to perform certain operations only on some elements of the matrix. So far it's working beautifuly, allowing me to write things such as:

    B(A>1) = 2*A(A>1) - 3

where B and A are TWMatrix objects of the same size.

Comment: @ticster: How are you able to write expressions like that without a dereference operator if those are the types of expressions you need the `TWDataPointer` for?  Or is your pointer-type not really a "pointer" in the true-sense, but a class that is encapsulating a pointer? If it's a class encapsulating a pointer, then what is wrong with just returning a non-const reference?

Comment: @ticster: Changing the return type wouldn't be enough but a `const` method vs non `const` would be. For the record I'm not recommending this.

Comment: @AJG85 Which is what I was doing already... but that limits me to 2 versions of (), not 3.

Comment: @ticster: Check out Item #3 in Scott Meyers *Effecitve C++* it covers this concept in detail and explains why you would or wouldn't want to do this.

Comment: @AJG85 Thanks for the tip. I'll check it out. If your curious as to my current solution, see the latest edit in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, this is because `D5` is not constant. It's the cv-qualification of this object which determines which operator is selected.

It seems like you are using the `const` qualification to disambiguate operator. I would use a different technique (for example a template parameter which is the output type you want, or the template parameter is the policy which defines how the return type is constructed, or even simpler, specify an output parameter which is what you want)

Comment: If I declare D5 as const, it does work. But I'm still confused. Going back to the int example, why does a = test(0,0) use the const version of the corresponding operator even if test is not declared const? Indeed, I've checked that this is the case using cout statements.

edit: The cout statements were placed in the operator implementation, to tell me which is being used. Don't mean to offend your intelligence, just clarifying in case you were wondering where I put them.

Comment: @ticster, may be you should post that example (not just the operator, but the all the pertinent code to get a simple working example)

Comment: @ticster - I figured that's where you put them - not many other places *to* put them.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For non-static member function. There is an implied object argument - the this pointer. And if a non-static member function is declared const, the this pointer would be const. So actually, your two functions looks like:

```
TWDataPointer<T> operator () (this, const TWMatrix<int> & I1, const TWMatrix<int> & I2)
{
     return TWDataPointer<T>(*this,I1,I2);
}

TWMatrix<T> operator () (const this, const TWMatrix<int> & I1, const TWMatrix<int> & I2) const 
{
    return SubMat(I1,I2);
}
```

I think now it is clear that why when your D5 is not const, the second function would never be called. You can use

```
TWMatrix<T> matrix = ((const TWMatrix<T>&)D5)(I1,I2);
```

as a workaround. But I don't think it is a good idea. It is very tricky that const and non-const methods get different result types.

For your int example, If the test is not const, I don't think the first function will be called.

Comment: I agree with you until your last sentence. Why does it behave differently for int?

Comment: I don't think the behavior for int is different. Did you try to put  printf() or breakpoints in both function to see which function is called actually?

Comment: Yes, I put cout in my operators and

    int a = test(0,0); // a NOT const

uses the const version of the () operator.